# Speed Tracer Server side Tracing for GWT

Tags: java, gwt, speed-test

Is the speed tracer server side tracing reserved for applications on the GAE, because i am checking http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/server-side-tracing.html and it only talks about the GAE, but I wanted to use it locally without the GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally it is available as part of SpringSource tc Server

Developer edition is available free of charge as part of the SpringSource Tool Suite or as a separate download

http://www.springsource.com/developer/tcserver

http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.0/devedition/html/ch04s04.html

Answer (score 1):

This blog post shows how speed tracer works behind the scenes and includes code that feeds Rails timing information back into the speed tracer UI:

http://www.igvita.com/2010/07/19/speed-tracer-server-side-tracing-with-rack/